# Could someone become Empress in China more than once?

Tags: china

I read a fictional story before where an empress was wrongly accused of black magic. The emperor loved her so much but the investigation didn't go deeper because the ministers were trying convince the emperor to just dethrone her which he did. After few years, he made his own investigation and he found out that his imperial royal consort did the planning and the story goes on.

At the end, the former empress was called and asked to be the emperor's empress again. My question is, can A dethroned empress be empress again if the allegations and accusations are proven wrong?

Comment: This question would benefit from research.

Comment: I'd dearly like to know which empress we are talking about here. There were rather a lot of them throughout the 5,000 years of Chinese history.

Comment: @T.E.D. The story actually reminds me strongly of a famous episode from Korean royal history. It's possible OP is mistaken about the country ...  I just can't remember the name of the king.

Comment: @T.E.D. Remembered it, King Sukjong, but the Korean story is actually slightly different than I recalled, so OP may indeed mean a chinese ruler. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukjong_of_Joseon )

Comment: It can, and they live happily ever after. (= Come up with a specific name. Otherwise it's a fairy tale.)

Comment: Well, it is really a fanfiction so I'm trying to know if that's valid because I also read a lot of Chinese History and I have never heard or read such situation.

Comment: Based on your comments, I've edited the question a bit to better match what I think you're asking for.

Comment: Empress Meng perhaps? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empress_Meng#Witch_craft_scandal

Comment: There isn't a constitution, so the answer lies in tradition. And I think our sample size of Empresses is statistically insignificant.  On the other hand on the absence of a constitution, the mandate of heaven applies, which can only be known ex post facto.

Answer (score 1):

The same woman became Queen Consort more than once in France, but to the best of my knowledge, the right pre-conditions never occurred in China. And these "pre-conditions" had nothing to do with "black magic."

Anne, Duchess of Brittany became Queen of France twice, first married to [Charles VIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_VIII_of_France) (born 1470), then to his cousin and successor, [Louis XII,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_XII_of_France) (born 1462). That's because Charles VIII died young (in 1498 at age 28), and was succeeded by a "peer."

The reason I give both birth years is because the two men were contemporaries, and for the same woman to be married to both of them was not out of the question. Most kingly successions, in France or in China, feature a much older king succeeded by a much younger one. It's unlikely that two such men would marry the same woman.

To the best of my knowledge, there were few (same generation) successions in China, and no successions where both the outgoing and incoming king/emperor selected the same woman as a Chief Consort (as opposed to a concubine).

Comment: Was there in fact a hard difference between a consort and a concubine? Some of the sources I dug up made the point that the Chinese didn't really hold to the western concept of lifetime binary marriage.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Yes, there was a difference in status, de jure, not necessarily de facto. The Consort had to come from a high-ranking noble family (very few eligible brides, the equivalent of Anne, Duchess of Brittany). A concubine could be "anyone." The sexiest concubine often had the king's ear, although the consort would take precedence in the court. The "Empress" Cixi started as a concubine and became Empress only after the Consort died under "mysterious" circumstances.